# how to get access to google bookmarks for other uses?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there some method to get to Google Chromes bookmarks? whether that be via an app, or through some kind of programming?

I have 100s of Google Chrome bookmarks, but I want to be able to display them better either on a website, or in an app if I could access them as data, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome Extensions have [bookmarks API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks). You can build a Chrome Extension that uploads your bookmarks to the server, exports them to a file or displays them, in any way you want, inside the browser. However, before you start, it might be a good idea to check [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/bookmarks) for existing extensions that may be already providing features that you are looking for.